# Find broken links (internal) for all authored links (components input & straight html) in Adobe CQ5.5 SP 2.1

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem, jcr, day-cq

We ran into an issue after installing SP2.1 on CQ5.5 which effects references update for all pages under a page that has been renamed using the "websites" console of CQ5. The issue is described here:

http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2012/12/13/cq5-5-sp2-1-linksreferences-are-not-updated-following-moverename/

The hotfix fixes future page name changes and updates the references in all other pages , whether the links are authored as html directly or through input widgets such as "pathfields".

However , we have discovered this bug pretty late and there have been lot of page re-naming done which resulted in broken links on existing pages where we have used pathfield component in dialog boxes for authors to refer to other pages. I would like to write some custom code using the LinkChecker api under the com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker package.  I am not able to find any sample code that CQ5 actually uses to perform the "reference updates" on page renames , to serve as a starting point.

I need inputs based on your experience , whether Linkchecker API is the best way forward or if there is some other API for checking all the authored links and generate a report on which links / pathfields have broken links .

Help appreciated.

I have checked:
1. the external link checker tool, which does report broken links, but only if the link is to some other external domain, so not useful in our case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkchecker is a Sling rewriter. Rewriters are strictly associated with the request. They operate on the HTML code generated by the CQ before it's returned to the client. If I understand correctly, you want to look for broken internal links in the whole site and the Linkchecker won't be very useful here.

Consider using [Groovy console](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console) to crawl over the `/content/your_site` looking for strings starting with `/content`. Then use `resourceResolver` to check if the found path exists. Sample script implementing this algorithm can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/trekawek/72b3515a6641ca5f4b29).

Comment: i have tried installing the groovy console as mentioned in your link , but I ran into dependency issues, the http://nexus.citytech.ctmsp.com/content/groups/public/com/citytechinc/aem/groovy/extension/aem-groovy-extension-bundle/    seems to have only 0.8.2 version, whereas the POM specs 0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.  update to 0.8.2  /  0.8.0-SNAPSHOT  did not resolve the dependency.  Also the read me specifies that for CQ5.5 you need to use the 3.xxx version, where can I download it from ?...  --thanks much !

Comment: Download released [3.1.0](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console/archive/3.1.0.zip) sources from the [Released](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console/releases) page on Github.

Comment: I installed the 3.1.0 on CQ5.5, when I browse to localhost:4502/etc/groovyconsole.html  I see a script input area, but I dont see the output area, is this a bug in 3.1.0 or should I look in the log files for the output?  .....am new to Groovy, sorry if my query is basics :)

Comment: I couldn't get the groovy output console working, but I used the logic in the above algorithm link and did some custom java coding using XPath to resolve the issue. thanks @Tomek